# what are the benefits of using java bridge for php?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

what are the benefits of using java bridge for php?
Is it ready/stable for production environment, is there a "best approach" to how installing it/managing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of good existing Java software, using your PHP application.

Three good examples I can think of right now are Lucene (free text indexing), BIRT (business intelligence/charts), and RapidMiner or Weka (datamining/ai/machine learning)

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is that you can use [html test units](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Im personally working with php java bridge right now, and I recommend this approach for reporting for example. You can use jasper reports and obtain good reports in your php framework.